Robot localization / sensor fusion for distance to wall
I am trying to estimate the distance of a robot relative to a wall in a 2.5D outdoor area. The distance measurements are sporadic and the raw data can be very noisy (I'm afraid there is not much that can be done about these readings at the moment), so I'm hoping to set up sensor fusion with the visual-inertial odometry running on the robot to have access to a more continuous value representing the estimated distance to a wall. I do also have an RTK-fixed GPS accurate to 10-ish cm, but of course it is discrete so I'm curious to know if you think I should integrate that in as well or not.
So my question here is, could robot_localization do this? for example, use the distance value as odom0 with all configs False except for x, then use the other sources all relative, and only for the x axis. If this approach is feasible, do you have any tips?
Or would you suggest using other sensor fusion approaches?

I think the answer depends a bit on your platform, sensors, and what you are trying to accomplish.
For example, if your sensor always measures the straight-line distance to the wall, that simplifies the problem. If the distance to the wall would change as the robot rotates (e.g., if it was a single-beam laser affixed to the robot), that's a harder problem.
But for now, I'm going to assume it's the former case, and either (a) your sensor always knows the straight-line distance to the wall, or (b) the robot is always aligned the same way with respect to the wall, and rotation does not affect the value of the measurement.
In that case, I would:

If you have wheel odometry, you can fuse the velocity from that source for all of your dimensions (X, Y, and yaw, assuming this is just a planar environment - I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by 2.5D here). If there's an IMU as well, then fuse angular velocity (likely just yaw velocity) from that source. That EKF instance will generate your odom->base_link transform.
I would then have second map->odom EKF. For that instance, I would assume that the origin of my world is somewhere along that wall. Then the measurement to the wall just becomes a measurement of my position in one linear axis (X or Y, in this case). So now you have an absolute pose reference for X or Y.
You can then fuse all the same sources you did in (1) for this instance.
Once all that is working, you can integrate the GPS data as you would for any standard navsat_transform_node setup.

